# Fetch data ageing for more than 90 days in oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, stored-procedures

I want to get data in oracle for more than 90 days from todays date. So I wrote the below query for fetching the data.

```
select a.span_id, a.link_id, b.rejected_date
 from tbl_fiber_inv_jobs a
 inner join tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress b
 on a.job_id = b.job_id
 where b.rejected_date is not null
 and b.rejected_date >= TRUNC(sysdate)-90;
```

But it's not fetching the data properly. Please let me know whether I am writing proper query or not for fetching data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get data in oracle for **more than 90 days from todays date**

To me, it looks like

```
and b.rejected_date <= TRUNC(sysdate)-90
```